# How can I use a UIButton in a UICollection supplementary view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios6, uicollectionview

I am attempting to place a UIButton in a UICollectionView supplementary view (footer). I have connected the UIButton using storyboards to a subclass of UICollectionViewCell and can change it's properties programmatically including the background image. However, when I wire up the touch up inside event of the button to a method, it does not fire. In fact, the button does not even appear to be responding visually to the user's touch. In troubleshooting, I attempted to add a UIButton to the collection view's header and see identical behavior. Adding the button to an unrelated view produces interaction effects when pressed.

Is there something special I need to do to implement a UIButton in a UICollection supplementary view?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A supplementary view should be a `UICollectionReusableView` (or subclass thereof), not a `UICollectionViewCell`.

Anyway, if the button's not responding, the first thing to do is check that all of its ancestor views have `userInteractionEnabled` set to `YES`.  Pause in the debugger once the button is on screen and do this:

```
(lldb) po [[UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
```

Find the button in the list and copy its address.  Then you can check it and each superview.  Example:

```
(lldb) p (BOOL)[0xa2e4800 isUserInteractionEnabled]
(BOOL) $4 = YES
(lldb) p (BOOL)[[0xa2e4800 superview] isUserInteractionEnabled]
(BOOL) $5 = YES
(lldb) p (BOOL)[[[0xa2e4800 superview] superview] isUserInteractionEnabled]
(BOOL) $6 = YES
(lldb) p (BOOL)[[[[0xa2e4800 superview] superview] superview] isUserInteractionEnabled]
(BOOL) $8 = YES
(lldb) p (BOOL)[[[[[0xa2e4800 superview] superview] superview] superview] isUserInteractionEnabled]
(BOOL) $9 = YES
(lldb) p (BOOL)[[[[[[0xa2e4800 superview] superview] superview] superview] superview] isUserInteractionEnabled]
(BOOL) $10 = NO
(lldb) po [[[[[0xa2e4800 superview] superview] superview] superview] superview]
(id) $11 = 0x00000000 <nil>
```

Here I found that all views up to the root (the `UIWindow`) return `YES` from `isUserInteractionEnabled`.  The window's superview is nil.

Comment: @robmayhoff: The issue was the fact that I had subclassed the wrong parent. Thank you for catching this!

Comment: @markdorison Ha ha, interesting.  I didn't really expect that to be the problem.

Comment: @robmayhoff: I was as surprised as you were when I made the one change and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I have a custom button which subclasses `UIControl` and put it inside a `UICollectionReusableView`. To make it work, I made every single subview of the control and its subviews' subviews handle no user interaction.

```
func disableUserInteractionInView(view: UIView) {
    view.userInteractionEnabled = false
    for view in view.subviews {
        self.disableUserInteractionInView(view)
    }
}

// My control has a subview called contentView which serves as a container
// of all my custom button's subviews.
self.disableUserInteractionInView(self.contentView)
```

Since adding that code, all event listeners to `.TouchUpInside` would fire, and the control will visually highlight when pressed down.