# UIScrollView within UICollectionViewCell Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` with a custom `UICollectionViewCell`. The `UICollectionView` scrolls horizontally, with each cell occupying all of the visible screen.

The `UICollectionViewCell` has a `UIView` subview, which in turn has a `UIScrollView` subview.

The `UIScrollView` is intended to scroll vertically, but it's not scrolling at all. I've tried setting the scroll view's `contentSize` with no success.

I suspect that the `UIScrollView` is not getting any touch events rather than it being a size issue.

Any suggestions?

EDIT >>

I'm now sure it's an event problem rather than anything specific to the `UIScrollView`.

I've now overridden the `pointInside:` method in the `UIView` in the `UICollectionViewCell` and can see that it now returns false every time I tap on it. In that case you'd think that the tap event would propagate to the next subview , but the `UIView` still isn't getting events. I've tried adding a `UIGestureRecognizer` to the `UIView` but it never registers a tap.

Could there be anything here intercepting the events that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to solve a similar problem with a scrollview, and your edit about events reminded me of this question (which solved my problem again) [How can I use a UIButton in a UICollection supplementary view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571994/how-can-i-use-a-uibutton-in-a-uicollection-supplementary-view)

Its possible you need to be using a UICollectionReusableView, not a UICollectionViewCell. Changing the class worked for me because I was using a button (and recently a scrollview) in a header.

However I've not tried for cells themselves. For capturing events from a UICollectionViewCell, maybe the following may help?
[Getting button action : UICollectionView Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757762/getting-button-action-uicollectionview-cell)

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable `userInteractionEnabled` for the `UIView` and enable it for your `UIScrollView`

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't solve the problem. Also, I occasionally load the UIView/UIScrollView outside of the CollectionView. When I disable userInteractionEnabled on the UIView and enable it on the UIScrollView, I don't get any scrolling there either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this was your problem, but it was mine - and I'm putting it here in case anyone else comes across this for the same reason.  I wanted to put a `UIScrollView` inside a `UICollectionReusableView` but by accident I had created my custom class as;

```
class CustomCellHeader: UICollectionViewCell {


}
```

instead of;

```
class CustomCellHeader: UICollectionReusableView {


}
```

Once I changed that, the `UIScrollView` within my header cell came to life!

Answer (score 0):

1. Embed the scrollable content in a ScrollView within the cell.
2. Add "UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout" to the UICollectionViewCell i.e.:

   ```
   class SomeCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

   }
   ```

Now scrolling within the cell should work.